# why does foreach only loop once?

Tags: prolog

The following code runs in SWI-Prolog:

```
?-foreach(member(X ,["1","2","3"]) ,(number_codes(Y,X),writeln(Y))).
1
false.

?- foreach(member(X ,["1","2","3"]) ,writeln(X)).
[49]
[50]
[51]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[foreach](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)/2 is more complex that [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2), and you hit the case where the used variable quantification makes a difference. Try instead

```
?- forall(member(X, ["1","2","3"]), (number_codes(Y,X), writeln(Y))).
1
2
3
```

true.

It seems that foreach/2 retains the bindings for `Y`.